# Union column value from different tables

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

I have three tables: `Table1`, `Table2`, and `Table3`.
All the three tables contains a key Column as a foreign key.

I want a SQLite query to return all distinct key columns from all three tables.

E.g.

Table 1:

```
+---------+---------+
|  Col1   |  Col2   | key |
+---------+---------+
| Val 1   | Val 2   | 100 |
| Val 3   | Val 6   | 101 |
| Val 4   | Val 7   | 103 |
| Val 5   | Val 8   | 104 |
+---------+---------+
```

Table 2 :

```
+---------+---------+
|  Col1   |  Col2   |       key |
+---------+---------+
| Val 1   | Val 2   |       100 |
| Val 3   | Val 6   |       101 |
| Val 4   | Val 7   |       105 |
| Val 50  | Val 18  |       106 |
+---------+---------+
```

So I want SQLite query that returns all distinct keys from both table in sorted order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
select key from table1  union select key from table2;
```

---

If you want the duplicates use  `union all`

```
select key from table1  union all select key from table2;
```